# Display pop up when user uploads file with the wrong extension in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

In the app below when the user does not upload a `.xls` file I want a pop up to be displayed. Now it appears only in the beginning but if upload another lets say `doc` file it is hidden. I do not care it is with `shinyalert` package or other method.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyalert)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyalert(),  # Set up shinyalert
  fileInput('file1', 'Choose xls file',
            accept = c(".xls")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$file1, {
    if (is.null(input$file1))
    # Show a modal when the button is pressed
    shinyalert("Oops!", "Something went wrong.", type = "error")
  }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This also resets the `fileInput`:

```
library(shiny)
library(tools)

ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("fileUpload")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  showModal(modalDialog("My startup modal..."))
  
  resetFileUpload <- reactiveVal(FALSE)
  output$fileUpload <- renderUI({
    resetFileUpload() # reactive dependency
    resetFileUpload(FALSE)
    fileInput('file1', 'Choose xls file', accept = c(".xls"))
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$file1, {
    if(file_ext(input$file1$name) != "xls"){
      resetFileUpload(TRUE)
      showModal(modalDialog("That's not a .xls file"))
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: a modal should be displayed when the app is launched for first time as well or when there is no file uploaded in general

Comment: Not uploading a file doesn't result in an event for `input$file1`.